# authentication popup asking for credentials under forms authentication on live server mvc4 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I have a mvc4 application and uses forms authentication in my web.config file , at IIS level have enabled Anonymous and Forms authentication , my website is running on https by default . But the problem is i am getting window authentication popup asking for username and password on some of the webpages , rest are workng fine .

here is my authentication tag from web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms"> 
   <forms name=".YAFNET_Authentication" 
      protection="All" timeout="43200" cookieless="UseCookies" /> 
</authentication>
```

Comment: Please post `<authentication ..>` tag in the web.config.

Comment: here is authentication tag from web.config <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".YAFNET_Authentication" protection="All" timeout="43200" cookieless="UseCookies" />
    </authentication>

Comment: can somebody suggest me possible solution ???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185228/auto-logging-in-to-another-asp-net-application-from-main-web-application